# OR clause in Regular Expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to validate some phone number which may come in the following two forms

123.231.457 or 011.44.321.326589

I was trying to use REGEXP_LIKE to validate it. However I want to know if we can use  OR clause in regexp_like ?

Here is my code

```
select count(1) digit_count
from dual 
where regexp_like(l_phone_no,'[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}');
```

which works fine for phone number of the form **123.231.4575** .

Comment: I figure out that adding a simple OR clause like this
select count(1) digit_count
from dual 
where regexp_like(l_phone_no,'[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}') OR regexp_like(l_phone_no,'[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}.[0-9]{6}');

solves my problem.

Comment: just a note: both your provided regex do not mach your given examples in line two even though you say they solve your problem :) both examples are missing a fourth digit after the second dot to match your regex

Comment: Database version please?

Comment: Your regular expression calls for four digits in the last portion of the phone number (as in a US phone number) but the example shown in the question has only three digits in the final portion of the number.  ???

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression matching group with it's native OR `(regex1|regex2)`

`([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{6})`

and escape the dot to actually match for dots and not any character

Answer (score 1):

As a note, `.` in a regular expression matches any character.  You should escape it, so the regular expression should look more like:

```
where regexp_like(l_phone_no,'[0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{3}[.][0-9]{4}');
```

This would apply to the expression in your comment as well.